# Inherit from Nested class inside inherited class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++98

I have the kinda weird problem which is already described in [nested class inherits from nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462781/nested-class-inherits-from-nested-class), but i start to get a little bit desperate by now.

I have 4 classes in 2 different files (i don't think that really matters), I'll also cut out the non-important stuff from the classes for a better overview

Request.h (With class Request and BaseCtx)

```
#ifndef REQUEST_H
#define REQUEST_H

#include <string>
#include <map>
class Request
{
public:
    Request() {};
    Request(Request &orig) {};
    class BaseCtx {};
    ~Request();
    /* ... More methods and functions */
private:
    /* ... More methods and functions */
};

#endif
```

Then there is my inherited class in p_TuStRequest.h (TuStRequest and TuStCtx)

```
#ifndef P_TU_ST_REQUEST_H
#define P_TU_ST_REQUEST_H
/*#include "Request.h"*/
class TuStRequest : public Request {
public:
    TuStRequest() {};
    TuStRequest(TuStRequest &orig);
    TuStRequest(std::string requestData) {};
    class TuStCtx : public Request::BaseCtx {
        std::string teid;
    };
private:
};
#endif
```

And my compiler (gcc version 4.2.4 (Gentoo 4.2.4-r01.16 p1.1) tells me the following:

> p_TuStRequest.h:14: error: expected class-name before '{' token Makefile:431: recipe for target 'p_TuStController.o' failed

For the ones which are not that familiar with compiler versions, vers. 4.2.4 is a little bit before c++11 support (so basically C++98)

Is this some kind if problem because the compiler (which I can't upgrade) is that old and does not support this or did I do something wrong fundamentally?

If this really is a compiler problem, is there a way around it? If i remove the nested class in TuStRequest everything builds fine, but i would need a second structure to prevent the usage of voidpointers (I really don't want to use voidpointers for the context)

PS: Yeah i know, some stuff is still missing (Copy Constructor and so on..) but that shouldn't be the issue here.

Comment: Did You try `typename Request::BaseCtx`?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk yes I already tried that, does not help either.

Comment: I'm afraid the code you posted is not a good [mre]. It doesn't compile to this error on its own, and when seemingly unrelated errors are fixed, it doesn't cause [any error at all](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/994a23230e9ba74a). Please reduce it some more.

Comment: I copy pasted your examples and it compiles with `g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0`. Also [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/u-GFAL) with version 4.1.2

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, thanks for you input, i edited the sample a little bit more, i didn't even thought about using godbolt as crosscheck, maybe its really some issue with our build enviroment...